# Make My JS Responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The original code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDeepMenu').deepMenu({
        "tileW": 64,
        "tileH": 100,
        "columns": 2,
        "rows": 2,
        "mark-type": "top-left",
        "mark-color": "#A1A1A1"
    });
});
```

I am trying to make this code responsive, so that the column and row values change based on screen size. To that end I have implemented this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 100 && $(window).width() < 200) {
        $('#myDeepMenu').deepMenu({
            "tileW": 64,
            "tileH": 100,
            "columns": 2,
            "rows": 2,
            "mark-type": "top-left",
            "mark-color": "#A1A1A1"
        });
    };
    else {
        $('#myDeepMenu').deepMenu({
            "tileW": 64,
            "tileH": 100,
            "columns": 3,
            "rows": 2,
            "mark-type": "top-left",
            "mark-color": "#A1A1A1"
        });
    };

});
```

The values I am focused on are the "columns" and "rows" portion. For some reason, adding the min-max width conditions make the function shut down entirely.

How would I go about changing the values of this function based on screen size?

Comment: if you want to make these change on `resize` you have to wrap `if else` in `$(window).rezise(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a function to get the new dimensions whenever the size is changed:

```
var h = $(window).height(), w = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){

   var nh = $(window).height(), nw = $(window).width();
   h = nh; w = nw;
   if nw > 100 && nw < 200) {
        $('#myDeepMenu').deepMenu({
            "tileW": 64,
            "tileH": 100,
            "columns": 2,
            "rows": 2,
            "mark-type": "top-left",
            "mark-color": "#A1A1A1"
        });
    };
    else {
        $('#myDeepMenu').deepMenu({
            "tileW": 64,
            "tileH": 100,
            "columns": 3,
            "rows": 2,
            "mark-type": "top-left",
            "mark-color": "#A1A1A1"
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: This seems not to work, though I am certain that it should. I am looking over it right now to see if there are any errors in syntax.

Comment: Did you get this to work? If not can you add a fiddle with all the necessary resources.

Comment: Got it. http://jsfiddle.net/T5CqA/ is the link to my JSFiddle. There are supposed to be images included, but for this testing purpose, I haven't included them. The main point I am trying to get at is that the "columns" and "rows" portion of the JS dictates how the items are arranged. I want these values to change based on browser width, so that they don't overflow. Hence why I change the value of "column" from 2 to 3. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: To clarify, when you click on "Desktop" or "Laptop", a menu of icons appear. What I am having trouble with is getting those menu options to change their row and column set-up based on browser width.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).width() > 100 && $(window).width() < 200) {
    $('#myDeepMenu').deepMenu({
        "tileW": 64,
        "tileH": 100,
        "columns": 2,
        "rows": 2,
        "mark-type": "top-left",
        "mark-color": "#A1A1A1"
    });
};  <----------------------- Semicolon in error?
```